# Determine who has a file open using C# - is there a way now?

Tags: c#, windows, system.io.file

I need to be able to check who has a file open using C#.  I found a few people asked this question before but they were all a long time ago with the latest being in 2012.  I was wondering if, in the last 5 years, has Microsoft added this ability to .net or maybe someone came out with a nuget package that is capable.

Here is the latest answer I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887244/determine-who-has-a-file-open-using-c-sharp/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use windows internal function NTQuerySystemInformation with undocumented parameter SystemHandleInformation for it. I don't know about c# implementation, but I know delphy code for it, and vb6 code. Check this links, it will help you to make your c# implementation.

[Delphi - get what files are opened by an application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575286/delphi-get-what-files-are-opened-by-an-application)

https://forum.sysinternals.com/topic14546.html

Comment: Here is the [pInvoke signature](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/ntdll.ntquerysysteminformation) for using that method in .NET.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the standard library still does not have suitable functions for this. There is a popular question about this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/937558/5665527.

Also, if you want to know who opened the file remotely - `net file` function may be useful (which is accessible via cmd). I believe that there are similar WinAPI functions on MSDN that could be implemented in a similar way.